# Wrong column type encountered with User-Defined Data Type

Tags: java, hibernate, sql-server-2014

I'm using hibernate to fetch some data from SQL Server 2014 database.

There is a Table which has columns of user-defined data types:

```
dbo.Nodos
    Id (PK, int, not null)
    Tipo (PK, FK, TipoNodo(tinyint), not null)
    Nombre (varchar(40), null)
    PosX (Coordenada(real), not null)
    PosY (Coordenada(real), not null)
    Label (varchar(8), not null)
```

Those data types are Coordenada and TipoNodo:

```
User-Defined Data Types
    dbo.Coordenada (real, not null)
    dbo.TipoNodo (tinyint, not null)
```

I'm mapping Nodos table as StopDTO class in Java:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Nodos")
public class StopDTO {

    /*
     * Atributos
     */
    @Id
    @Column(name = "Id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "Tipo", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Integer tipo;
    @Column(name = "Nombre", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String nombre;
    @Column(name = "PosX", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Float posx;
    @Column(name = "PosY", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Float posy;
    @Column(name = "Label", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String label;
    ...
```

The problem comes when I query StopDTOs (using a NamedNativeQuery), I'm getting the following message:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException:
>   Schema-validation: wrong column type encountered in column [PosX] in
>   table [Nodos]; found [coordenada (Types#REAL)], but expecting [float
>   (Types#FLOAT)]    at
>   org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaValidatorImpl.validateColumnType(SchemaValidatorImpl.java:165)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaValidatorImpl.validateTable(SchemaValidatorImpl.java:150)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaValidatorImpl.performValidation(SchemaValidatorImpl.java:95)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaValidatorImpl.doValidation(SchemaValidatorImpl.java:62)
>   ...

Is this problem solved by implementing a couple of UserTypes for Coordenada and TipoNodo? What can I do if it's not?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

Indeed, it was what expected: develop a pair of UserType. I'll post the code in case somebody needs:

**TipoNodoUserType**

```
package com.mycompany.usertype;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Types;
import java.util.Objects;

import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionImplementor;
import org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.ShortTypeDescriptor;
import org.hibernate.usertype.UserType;

public class TipoNodoUserType implements UserType {

    public static final TipoNodoUserType INSTANCE = new TipoNodoUserType();

    @Override
    public int[] sqlTypes() {
        return new int[] {Types.TINYINT};
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    @Override
    public Class returnedClass() {
        return Short.class;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object x, Object y) throws HibernateException {
        return Objects.equals(x, y);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode(Object x) throws HibernateException {
        return Objects.hashCode(x);
    }

    @Override
    public Object nullSafeGet(ResultSet rs, String[] names, SessionImplementor session, Object owner)
            throws HibernateException, SQLException {
        String columnName = names[0];
        Short columnValue = (Short) rs.getObject(columnName);
        return columnValue == null ? null : columnValue;
    }

    @Override
    public void nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement st, Object value, int index, SessionImplementor session)
            throws HibernateException, SQLException {
        if(value == null){
            st.setNull( index, Types.TINYINT );
        }else{
            String stringValue = ShortTypeDescriptor.INSTANCE.toString((Short)value);
            st.setString(index, stringValue);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object deepCopy(Object value) throws HibernateException {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isMutable() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Serializable disassemble(Object value) throws HibernateException {
        return (Serializable) value;
    }

    @Override
    public Object assemble(Serializable cached, Object owner) throws HibernateException {
        return cached;
    }

    @Override
    public Object replace(Object original, Object target, Object owner) throws HibernateException {
        return original;
    }

}
```

**CoordenadaUserType**

```
package com.mycompany.usertype;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Types;
import java.util.Objects;

import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionImplementor;
import org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.FloatTypeDescriptor;
import org.hibernate.usertype.UserType;

public class CoordenadaUserType implements UserType {

    public static final CoordenadaUserType INSTANCE = new CoordenadaUserType();

    @Override
    public int[] sqlTypes() {
        return new int[] {Types.REAL};
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    @Override
    public Class returnedClass() {
        return Float.class;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object x, Object y) throws HibernateException {
        return Objects.equals(x, y);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode(Object x) throws HibernateException {
        return Objects.hashCode(x);
    }

    @Override
    public Object nullSafeGet(ResultSet rs, String[] names, SessionImplementor session, Object owner)
            throws HibernateException, SQLException {
        String columnName = names[0];
        Float columnValue = (Float) rs.getObject(columnName);
        return columnValue == null ? null : columnValue;
    }

    @Override
    public void nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement st, Object value, int index, SessionImplementor session)
            throws HibernateException, SQLException {
        if(value == null){
            st.setNull( index, Types.REAL );
        }else{
            String stringValue = FloatTypeDescriptor.INSTANCE.toString((Float)value);
            st.setString(index, stringValue);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object deepCopy(Object value) throws HibernateException {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isMutable() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Serializable disassemble(Object value) throws HibernateException {
        return (Serializable) value;
    }

    @Override
    public Object assemble(Serializable cached, Object owner) throws HibernateException {
        return cached;
    }

    @Override
    public Object replace(Object original, Object target, Object owner) throws HibernateException {
        return original;
    }

}
```

**StopDTO**

```
    @Entity
@Table(name = "Nodos")
public class StopDTO implements java.io.Serializable{

    /*
     * Atributos
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8171715812406080593L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "Id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Integer id;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "Tipo", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @Type(type = "com.mycompany.usertype.TipoNodoUserType")
    private Short tipo;
    @Column(name = "Nombre", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String nombre;
    @Column(name = "PosX", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @Type(type = "com.mycompany.usertype.CoordenadaUserType")
    private Float posx;
    @Column(name = "PosY", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @Type(type = "com.mycompany.usertype.CoordenadaUserType")
    private Float posy;
    @Column(name = "Label", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String label;
    ...
    // Don't forget to code an empty constructor, setters/getters for every attribute and implementing hashCode and equals methods (as we're implementing Serializable interface).
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check the dialect configured in Hibernate, it should be SQLServer2008Dialect.

Comment: I've got: configuration.setProperty(AvailableSettings.DIALECT, "org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect");